# How to log, which processes did specific syscalls?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

Recently I've found that many processes/demons like to issue unneeded `fsync()` syscalls, increasing a little bit their stability, on the price of hugely decreasing the general performance of the whole system. I want to stop this non-cooperative behavior. However, first I need to somehow find them.

I think, the most ideal thing would be, if I could somehow set-up a "monitor" for a specific type of system calls, and log the data of the process which called it.

In my case, if any process does an `fsync()` syscall, I want to know it. Most ideally, it should be a syslog entry, or in the `dmesg`.

I've read a little bit about auditd, but I am not sure, if it even could do that.

Comment: Yes audit can do that. It's the most obvious way to do that. The documentation isn't that great but there are many answers on this site that show how to run `auditctl` to do similar things.

Comment: This is why people like Solaris DTrace.  This sort of system-wide thing is a one-liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing a recent distribution is being used,  the `bpftrace` does come handy. For it, in Debian 10, there is a need to install it:

```
apt install bpftrace
```

Then using `synsnoop.bt`, to listen system-wide to *sync related syscalls:

```
# syncsnoop.bt
Attaching 7 probes...
Tracing sync syscalls... Hit Ctrl-C to end.
TIME      PID    COMM             EVENT
03:15:35  443    dhclient         tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_fsync
^C
```

> This tool works by tracing sync(2) variants via tracepoints: sync(2),
>   syncfs(2), fsync(2), fdatasync(2), sync_file_range(2), and msync(2).
>   The overhead of this tool is expected to be negligible, as the rate of
>   sync(2) is typically very infrequent.

Or using `bpftrace` scripting language:

```
# ./sync.bt 
Attaching 7 probes...
Tracing sync syscalls... Hit Ctrl-C to end.
TIME      PID    COMM             EVENT
08:09:53 443    dhclient         tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_fsync
^C
```

`sync.bt` source for logging all *sync* related system calls:

```
#!/usr/bin/bpftrace
BEGIN {
  printf("Tracing sync syscalls... Hit Ctrl-C to end.\n"); 
  printf("%-9s %-6s %-16s %s\n", "TIME", "PID", "COMM", "EVENT");
}

tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_sync, 
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_syncfs, 
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_fsync, 
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_fdatasync, 
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_sync_file_range, 
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_msync
{
  time("%H:%M:%S ");
  printf("%-6d %-16s %s\n", pid, comm, probe);
}
```

PS from pages 293 and 294 of Brendan Gregg's [BPF Performance Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136554822)

Answer (score 1):

Beside the accepted answer, also [auditd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditd) can do that, as @Gilles mentioned in a comment.

The auditd can be controlled by the [auditctl](https://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) command, and an

```
auditctl -S fsync,fdatasync,...
```

limits the logged syscalls to our wanted ones.

Comment: Well, this answer is a partial one - it is because instead of playing with auditd/auditctl, I solved the problem by @Rubeiro's bpftrace solution. If a more detailed answer is coming, I will delete this and upvote that.